# correct version compatibility matrix for expo, npm, node, react-native, typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, npm, npx

I am doing the [react-native typescript setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript) which I ran

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

I installed typescript

```
npm install -g typescript
```

- 'npx --v' -> 6.14.15
- 'npm view react-native version' -> 0.67.2
- 'npm view typescript version' -> 4.5.5
- 'node -v' -> v12.22.9

and then immediately, I get errors from the template ->

```
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:47:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'AbortController'.

47 interface AbortController {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:435:15
    435 declare class AbortController {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'AbortController' was also declared here.
```

Once I solve this my next question is having all [developers use the same tool versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011527/setting-up-a-proper-dev-environment-with-ci-for-react-native-typescript-nodejs) to avoid this dependency hell.  The only one dealing with dep hell will be the person doing the upgrade.  everyone else will magically get their tool and lib versions changed hopefully!!!

Comment: which OS are you installing on? This information is useful as well as.

Comment: MAC OS 12.1.  I miss the days of java where compatibility was so much easier. This stuff reminds me of ruby and that mess of always running into compatibility issues.

Comment: Any tutorial with all compatible version setup would be great rather than setups that just install latest which may not be compatible.  Is there such a tutorial?  Most tutorials install latest which is a good risk of not working later in time.

Comment: By the way, what you mean exactly for  compatibility matrix?

Comment: 3rdparty libC has version 3 and version 4.  libA depends on version 3 while libB depends on version 4 and microservice A depends on libA and libB.  The same happens in tooling all the time where different versions do not play well together or the tooling does not play well with current package.json format or javascript source code files (ie. different typescript versions).

Comment: Then, my references to use node ci instead of node install will guarantee you to be congruent with a project.

Comment: is this same as npm ci and npm install?  If so, it sounds horrible as instead of validating all the correct versions, it wipes your node_modules directory each time so it is very slow and inefficient.  In java, they just check the version and if you do not have it, grab the correct version.    is there not a middle ground yet in npm where it caches all versions and uses the ones for that project.  java stores all versions outside the project so every project can lock onto proper version without installing the same version in 5 projects.

Comment: not to mention much longer CI build times.  CI's are designed with caches so in java, we cache all the downloads and until the deps list changes(hash on the file), the cache is re-used so no need to re-install jars/modules every time like npm is doing.  That is a huge time suck.

Comment: @CarmineTambascia oops, I forgot to reference your name.  I wonder if they are working on the above though.

Comment: I don't think this is something achievable with only npm that is node package manager and not something related directly to other services/ framework such expo, RN etc. I mean maybe for this a docker image would suite the purpose, as when we talk about RN we are in the domain of cross platform development and that implies way other layers and SDK

Comment: I am only talking about 'moving' the local node_modules directory into ~/node_modules/{modules}/{versions} instead of {project}/node_modules/{modules} with no version.  This allows all projects to share local modules of the same version and use different versions.  A setting on npm would be amazing for that @CarmineTambascia (I shamelessly steal this idea from maven/gradle/ivy since they do that).

Comment: I would say for the moment another good approach could be use docker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, today I ran

npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript

in another directory and running 'tsc' works

tsc still does not work in the other MyApp directory and a comparison shows a whole slew of things that are not different versions.  I have no idea why but my guess is this is a 'always using latest versions' issue.  At least the template locks into a version(I think) so versions will not change on my working project(I hope).

Comment: if I am not wrong React Native project as is based on node.js has a package.json as well. So then if you take another package.json-lock, rubbing 'node ci" should install exact dependencies included in that file, excalty those, same version number and not the latest version that as you wrote in the above comment, isnt guarantee would be stable with old one environment.

Comment: @CarmineTambascia Well, I am not sure.  The only difference was the order I ran commands AND the day I ran them and BOTH projects had different versions in package.json generated from the template.  One could compile with typescript and the other could not.  so one package.json had a incompatible list of versions.

Comment: All tutorials are really bad on correctly setting up node and npm and tooling in general instead of having a good bootstrap that I finally think I may have found.  https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-and-how-to-use-stable-node-and-npm-versions-across-your-project-team-a4886f51a96c

Comment: I don't know what it says there in the "tutorial" because is a paid content. Nevertheless tutorials as we know in this area get out of date quite soon, and especially they hide or take for granted many part and focus only on what they teach. In general I do believe understanding how npm works is a good start. I would check this where many people pointed out many interesting parts, if you have a project already "started" go for npm ci instead of npm install https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci

Comment: I would also use that if you "follow" a tutorial and a package-lock.json is available( that should be included in a project in order to run proper "dependencies" version that align with the project, so grab that file put in your src and run npm ci

Comment: odd, the links I gave are not paid except medium and in that case you can clear your cookies and read it or use a new browser.

Comment: after have read some content medium ask for signup to membership, that I don't have. Nevertheless your point regarding the package management in java could be interesting in give some hint improvement in npm world. Do you have some update link to get a grasp of this philosophy and eventually one can adapt to own team working with npm?

Comment: @CarmineTambascia I also do not have medium membership.  I found I could add these settings in .npmrc file
engine-strict=true
save-exact=true.  This ensures ALL developers are on same EXACT version with no magical upgrades (which seems to always lead to the 'well, it works for me syndrome' at some point in time.