# Is this an npx bug since package.json lists one version but npx runs a different version?

Tags: npx

I just ran this command

```
npx tsc -v
```

and it said Version 4.5.5.

Then, I look in package.json and package-lock.json and they say typescript 4.4.4.  When I look in node_modules/typescript/package.json, I see version 4.5.5.  Why is npx not detecting this and throwing an error OR better yet, doing what java does and delete the old one and install the correct one.

Even better would be caching all downloaded versions outside the repo for projects to use but only using the version that my project uses so projects can share versions OR not share versions easily without wasting disk space like it is done now(the gradle/maven-java way).

Comment: Give a [mre]; do they say `"typescript": "4.4.4"` or do they say `"typescript": "^4.4.4"`? 4.5.5 is the latest version that matches the latter semver (see https://semver.npmjs.com/), so I'd guess that. Run `npm ls typescript` to see all the dependencies on that package.

Comment: OMG, great point.  I did not know people did that in npm/node land.  HUGE OUCH.  no wonder we have so much 'well, it works for me on my machine' going on.  I will lock all these versions down preventing that syndrome.  I don't get why people think ^4.4.4 is a good idea.  at some point, some library breaks their compatibility on accident.  It is a certainty and I would rather not deal with that until we decide to upgrade so that only one developer deals with it and is not surprised by accidental upgrades.  thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: You don't get _"accidental upgrades"_ with a lockfile, that's what `package-lock.json` is for - it has the specific resolved versions for the whole dependency tree. And you _did_ know that, because https://stackoverflow.com/a/71014037/3001761 told you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think I read that answer after my above post so I did not know it but learned it later yes.  Unfortunately, I removed all the ^ from package-lock.json and that just broke :(.  I really need a command npm install xxxxx@latest with specific version without the darn carot.  does that exist or do I have to spend 4 hours figuring out version numbers?

Comment: in better news, I am really close to having this all worked out and knowing it pretty solid I think.  Only a few issues/kinks left I think.  I really appreciate all the help though it sounds like you are mad every time for some reason.